# Error : SQL insertion error at the time of task failed using CloudSqlQueryOperator

Tags: python, airflow

I have some doubt related to my python code. Here I have created one DAG with two task one is executing fine and another one is failed(forcefully I have mentioned wrong values for check the scenario).

I am trying to implement on_failure_callback at the time of task failure. and at the time of task failure need to insert the error message in GCP mysql.

Here in below code I have one method "sql_failed_task" which is responsible for pushing the error message and calling CloudSqlQueryOperator.

But Insertion is not working properly : Executing: "["INSERT INTO task_exception (failure_reason) VALUES ('{{ti.xcom_pull(key='the_message')}}')"]"

error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'the_message')}}')' at line 1")

Below code(There is no indention error in my code, might be you can see here because of some editing or copy paste) :

```
import os

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators import dataproc_operator
from airflow import models
from airflow.hooks.mysql_hook import MySqlHook
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcp_sql_operator import 
CloudSqlQueryOperator

db_config = Variable.get("analytics_audit_db_properties", 
deserialize_json=True)

GCSQL_MYSQL_USER =db_config["GCSQL_MYSQL_USER"]
GCSQL_MYSQL_PASSWORD =db_config["GCSQL_MYSQL_PASSWORD"]
GCSQL_MYSQL_PUBLIC_PORT =db_config["GCSQL_MYSQL_PUBLIC_PORT"]
GCSQL_MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME =db_config["GCSQL_MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME"]
GCP_PROJECT_ID=db_config["GCP_PROJECT_ID"]
GCP_REGION=db_config["GCP_REGION"]
GCSQL_MYSQL_INSTANCE_NAME_QUERY 
=db_config["GCSQL_MYSQL_INSTANCE_NAME_QUERY"]

SQL = [
     "INSERT INTO task_exception (failure_reason) VALUES 
('{{ti.xcom_pull(key='the_message')}}')",
]

 mysql_kwargs = dict(
    user=quote_plus(GCSQL_MYSQL_USER),
    password=quote_plus(GCSQL_MYSQL_PASSWORD),
    public_port=GCSQL_MYSQL_PUBLIC_PORT,
    project_id=quote_plus(GCP_PROJECT_ID),
    location=quote_plus(GCP_REGION),
    instance=quote_plus(GCSQL_MYSQL_INSTANCE_NAME_QUERY),
    database=quote_plus(GCSQL_MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME)
)

os.environ['AIRFLOW_CONN_PROXY_MYSQL_TCP'] = \
    "gcpcloudsql://{user}:{password}@{public_port}/{database}?" \
    "database_type=mysql&" \
    "project_id={project_id}&" \
    "location={location}&" \
    "instance={instance}&" \
    "use_proxy=True&" \
    "sql_proxy_use_tcp=True".format(**mysql_kwargs)

connection_names = [
    "proxy_mysql_tcp",
]
tasks = []

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 1, 1),
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=30),    
}

with models.DAG(
        dag_id='Dag_failure_callback_example_2',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1)
 ) as dag:

def my_task_py():
        print('Hello World')

def sql_failed_task(context):
    print('inside sql_failed_task')
    print("context exception : ", context.get('exception'))
    task_instance = context['task_instance']
    exception = context.get('exception')
    task_instance.xcom_push(key="the_message", value=str(exception))
    print('after push')
    connection_name = 'proxy_mysql_tcp'
    failed_alert = CloudSqlQueryOperator(
        gcp_cloudsql_conn_id=connection_name,
        task_id="sql_failed_task" + connection_name,
        sql=SQL)
    failed_alert.execute(context=context)




    my_task_1 = PythonOperator(task_id='my_task_1', 
python_callable=my_task_py, dag=dag)


create_dataproc_cluster = dataproc_operator.DataprocClusterCreateOperator(
    task_id='create_dataproc_cluster',
    project_id='trim********',
    cluster_name='airflow-*****',
    num_workers=2,
    zone='europe-west1-c',
    master_machine_type='n1-standard-1',
    worker_machine_type='n1-standard-1',
    on_failure_callback=sql_failed_task,
    dag=dag)

    my_task_1 >> create_dataproc_cluster
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `provide_context=True` in `my_task_1`.

```
my_task_1 = PythonOperator(task_id='my_task_1', provide_context=True,
python_callable=my_task_py, dag=dag)
```

> :param provide_context: if set to true, Airflow will pass a set of
>           keyword arguments that can be used in your function. This set of
>           kwargs correspond exactly to what you can use in your jinja
>           templates. For this to work, you need to define `**kwargs` in your
>           function header.

Comment: No, It's not working, we are forcefully failing create_dataproc_cluster task. my_task_1 is not having any role anyway I tried it . It's not working. Same thing I tried for create_dataproc_cluster task also, But it's not worked.